# Missing /dev/dsp under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I am using an integrated Realtek HD Audio sound card, normal audio output works as expected.

Nautilus doesn't show 'dsp' in the /dev folder. Now, why isn't it there?

In the 'Users and Groups' settings Ubuntu says I'm already in the user group 'audio', but just to be sure I also ran a `sudo gpasswd -a underyx audio`. Still have the same problem.

Comment: What's up with this edit proposal? http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/203 If I understand correctly, then you totally changed it, somehow, invalidating the existing answers? Please post your new question as, er, a new question instead. (@Olli, if you care to explain more: please do!)

Comment: if I understand correctly then you changed the question in something totally different? That has been rolled back; see [the revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/244173/revisions) and the [edit review](http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/203). (And @grawity, if your answer was based on revision 2, then please rollback the 3rd revision? You deleted your answer while I was typing this as a comment to that deleted answer.)

Comment: @Arjan: It seems that Underyx himself has added the new question – immediately after posting the initial version (I think the timeout is 5 minutes since posting), so it got merged by SU to "Revision 1". I suppose this would make Olli's edit valid. (Can't say I approve of Underyx's question change, though.)

Comment: Okay, @grawity, that question change was bad of course. Now that the original is back, I guess your answer applies (too)? (I've no idea if the currently accepted answer applies...)

Comment: In reply to your comment on my ex-answer: Output redirection will attempt to _create_ the file if it doesn't exist, giving the "Permission denied" error (because you are not allowed to modify `/dev`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `pulseaudio` you don't need `/dev/dsp` device. At least according these source:
[PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio)

> For OSS applications, PulseAudio
>   provides the `padsp` utility, which
>   replaces device files such as
>   `/dev/dsp`, tricking the applications
>   into believing that they have
>   exclusive control over the sound card.
>   In reality, their output is rerouted
>   through PulseAudio.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the command `pacat /dev/urandom > padsp`